# What is going wrong in this SQL executemany command?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, insert

I'm using the sql_connection executemany command in my python script to load hundreds or thousands of rows into my table at once. The code where I do this is below:

```
try:
            items = []
            global jsontuple
            for tup in jsontuple:
                items.append(tup)
            global tweet_count
            stmnt = "INSERT INTO tbltweet" " (id,text,posted,username,retweetCount,link,friends,followers,partisanship)"" VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            sql_cursor.executemany(stmnt, items)
            sql_connection.commit()
            num_tweets = len(jsontuple)
            tweet_count += num_tweets
except:
            sql_connection.rollback()
```

The global jsontuple is a tuple of tuples, where each of its constituent tuples contains the variables referenced in the insert statement. Since the executemany queryy needs the data to be in a list-type format, I take every tuple in jsontuple and append it to a list called items. I then execute the executemany query.

Problem is, I'm getting the rollback on almost every call to this function (however, sometimes the function executes without issue). What's wrong with the way I've set this up? I've triple checked to make sure that the formatting in the SQL table aligns with the query I'm making in my script. I've also tried just using the tuple of tuples as my data for the command instead of transforming it into a list, but the results are exactly the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for mysql or sqlserver? I will guess each `%s` needs to be in double quotes if it's SQL Server and if the sqlstmt is a literal string.

Comment: for the purpose of solving this issue change your except block to be except Exception as e: print e Then check there error message when it fails. Post the error for further help.